# Object doesn't support this property or method: 'xmldoc2.importNode'

Tags: vbscript, xml-parsing

I am trying to copy nodes from one XML document into another.

`Project` is a root element inboth documents and I want to select all `ItemGroup` elements from first document and insert them before `Import` element in the second document. Unfortunately, I get

```
Object doesn't support this property or method: 'xmldoc2.importNode'
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
Set xmldoc1 = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmldoc1.async = false
xmldoc1.load WScript.Arguments(0)

Set xmldoc2 = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmldoc2.async = false
xmldoc2.load WScript.Arguments(1)

Set importNode = xmldoc2.selectSingleNode("//Project/Import")

Set nodes = xmldoc1.selectNodes("//Project/ItemGroup")
For Each node In nodes
    Set newNode = xmldoc2.importNode(node, True)
    xmldoc2.insertBefore newNode, importNode
Next
```

How should I fix the code?

EDIT:

Thanks to @Ekkehard.Horner, I solved the issue. Here is the updated code

```
Set xmldoc1 = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmldoc1.async = false
xmldoc1.load WScript.Arguments(0)

Set xmldoc2 = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmldoc2.async = false
xmldoc2.load WScript.Arguments(1)

Set importNode = xmldoc2.selectSingleNode("//Project/Import")

Set nodes = xmldoc1.selectNodes("//Project/ItemGroup")
For Each node In nodes
    Set newNode = node.cloneNode(true)
    xmldoc2.documentElement.insertBefore newNode, importNode
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for importNode state:

> [This sample code uses features that were first implemented in MSXML
>   5.0 for Microsoft Office Applications.]

I'd try to use

1. "Msxml2.DOMDocument" or "Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0" instead of "Microsoft.XMLDOM"
2. .cloneNode instead of .importNode